# How to get the number out of the string

Tags: java, string

```
public static void availiablePawnMoves(String unitName, String targetPos) {//unitname = "1A"
    String onlyGridNumberForName; //here goes just the number (this could also be an int if possible)
    System.out.println(onlyGridNumberForName);
```

I would like to know how get the number from unitName, The unitName string is "1A" or it could be "2A" so it can't be hardcoded to be one string. Then the number should go into onlyGridNumberForName How do I do this? (Please have mercy I'm just a noob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
String intValue = unitName.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

You can also try this.

```
 String intValue = unitName.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that the number will always be only one character and that it will come first, substring (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) will get you what you want:

```
String onlyGridNumberForName = unitName.substring(0,1);
```

If you want it as an integer, you can use parseInt from the Integer wrapper to do that:

```
int gridNumber = Integer.parseInt(unitName.substring(0,1));
```

If you could have a board that could include 2+ digit numbers, you can create a while loop that will determine how many numbers to extend your substring:

```
int i = 0;
while (Character.isDigit(unitName.charAt(i))) {
    i++;
}
// now i points to the first non-digit, which makes it the second arg to substring
String gridNumber = unitName.substring(0,i);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detailed info! This sure helps!